# how to generate many threads by std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

As we all known, we can generate one thread by std::thread t1(func); [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)
But how can we create 20 threads by vector?

Comment: If I get it right you can loop and each iteration create new thread, add it to vector and so on

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just thought I can push pointer into vector and then new the thread like this "threads_.emplace_back(new std::thread(&ThreadPool::Process, this, i));". thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example solution would be:

```
std::vector<std::thread> my_threads{};
my_threads.reserve(20);

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    my_threads.emplace_back([i]{
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] Going to sleep\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{1});
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] Hey I'm back :)\n";
    });

for(auto& thread : my_threads)
    if(thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
```

Pay attention to the last tree lines.
If you don't join or detach your threads you'll get an abort.
This prevents your application from leaking unmanaged threads.

Comment: You don't need the `if (thread.joinable())` conditional. "A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable. "